# Check if user input has a letter or number at specific indexes

Tags: java, user-input

I have need to check if a user input follows the Canadian postal code format, which is

```
"L#L #L#"
```

Where `L` is an uppercase letter and `#` is any digit

How do would I do this?
Would I have to break it down and look at each letter?

I am very new to java, so I would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Have you tried it out, have you tested some code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I researched and only came up with string builders seeing if any numbers are present at all. Nothing about checking specific indexes. Code wise I have no clue where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any letter/number is OK:

```
 if (str.matches("[A-Z]\\d[A-Z] \\d[A-Z]\\d"))
     // OK
```

If only certain combinations are valid, you'll need something more complicated, like storing valid values in a Set and asserting the entered values exist there.

Comment: Thank you! I cant believe it was that simple. I didnt know you could do chain regex like this! I just came over from c++ and had to remake this program and this came up and i had no clue